Derivation of massive photon propagator
I'm trying to derive the massive photon propagator using the path integral formalism for a theory with
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\dfrac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} + \dfrac{1}{2} m^2 A_\mu A^\nu, \text{with } F_{\mu\nu} = A_\mu \partial_\nu - A_\nu \partial_\mu.
$$
We may rewrite this as
$$
\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{2} A_\mu \left[ (\partial^2 + m^2) g^{\mu\nu} - \partial^\mu \partial^\nu \right] A_\nu .
$$
The path integral with a source is
\begin{aligned}
Z[J_\mu] &= \int [\mathcal{D} A] \exp \left(-i\int \text{d}^4\,x \mathcal{L} - J_\mu(x) A^\mu (x) \right),\\
&= \int [\mathcal{D} A] \exp \left(-i\int \text{d}^4\,x \dfrac{1}{2} A_\mu \left[ (\partial^2 + m^2) g^{\mu\nu} - \partial^\mu \partial^\nu \right] A_\nu - J_\mu(x) A^\mu (x) \right).
\end{aligned}
By Fourier transforming (I denote with a tilde the transformed fields), I get to
$$
Z[J_\mu] = \int [\mathcal{D} A] \exp \left(-\dfrac{i}{2}\int \dfrac{\text{d}^4\,p}{(2\pi)^4} \dfrac{1}{2} \tilde{A}_\mu (p) \left[ (p^2 + m^2) g^{\mu\nu} - p^\mu p^\nu \right] \tilde{A}_\nu (-p) - \tilde{J}_\mu(p) \tilde{A}^\mu (-p) + \tilde{J}_\mu(-p) \tilde{A}^\mu (p) \right).
$$
I would like to now make the field redefinition
$$
\tilde{B}_\mu = \tilde{A}_\mu + J_\mu \left[ (p^2 + m^2) g^{\mu\nu} - p^\mu p^\nu \right]^{-1},
$$
so I can arrive -- after undoing all the transforms -- to the usual
$$
Z[J] = Z[0]\times \exp \left(\dfrac{i}{2}\int \text{d}^4\,x\,\text{d}^4\,y J_\mu (x) \Delta(x-y)^{\mu,\nu} J_\nu (y) \right),
$$
where
$$
\Delta(x-y)^{\mu,\nu} := \int \dfrac{\text{d}^4 \,p}{(2\pi)^4} e^{i(x-y)p} \left[ (p^2 + m^2) g^{\mu\nu} - p^\mu p^\nu \right]^{-1}
$$
is the FT of the inverse of the "massive photon operator". From here on I would be able to obtain the photon propagator through the 2P function.
Now, the problem is that I do not see how to obtain $\left[ (p^2 + m^2) g^{\mu\nu} - p^\mu p^\nu \right]^{-1}$. I saw online that it should be (in a certain gauge)
$$
\left[ (p^2 + m^2) g^{\mu\nu} - p^\mu p^\nu \right] = \dfrac{g^{\mu\nu} - \dfrac{p^\mu p^\nu}{m^2}}{p^2 - m^2 +i\epsilon}, \tag{1}
$$
but I do not find that (1) is the inverse of $\left[ (p^2 + m^2) g^{\mu\nu} - p^\mu p^\nu \right]$!
Can someone help me see where I've gone wrong?

You've got a few errors in there like a squared minus sign, and perhaps you should use exp with parentheses to make it more clear what's inside the exponent.

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/798220
